# Is there a way to make jam or chutney without Gelatin / Pectin?

Tags: substitutions, jam, gelling-agents, gelatin

I was wondering if there is a way to make jam without going through a gelatin type product. There is no real motive behind that question, except for curiosity

Comment: I personally just add dehydrated dry-frozen fruit to the jam to absorb excess water, add flavor, and add pectin. Just keep a bag in the freezer and throw a handful in your jam to thicken it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the National Center for Home Food Preservation:
[Making Jelly without Added Pectin](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_07/jelly_without_pectin.html)
[Making Jam without Added Pectin](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_07/jam_without_pectin.html)

- Use a mixture of 3/4 ripe and 1/4 under-ripe high-pectin fruits. Under-ripe or just barely ripe fruit contains the most pectin.
- Cook the fruit with cores and peels to add extra pectin (but do remove stems or pits). Put through a sieve before adding sugar and spices.
- Citrus peel contains lots of pectin, so consider adding some of it to your mixture.

Fruits low in pectin: apricots, blueberries, cherries, peaches, pears, raspberries, and strawberries. That's not saying you can't make jam/jelly/butter from these without added pectin. It just may be a little more difficult than, say, using apples. In fact, as an example, here's a [pear butter recipe](http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/pear_butter/) w/o pectin.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you can with all fruits, but some fruits, like fruits like apples, blackberries, gooseberries, crab apples, cranberries, and grapes are naturally high in pectin and might produce the desired effect without extra help.

Comment: Exactly - I make apple butter every fall, pectin free.

Comment: This might be semantic nitpicking on my part- but it isn't "pectin free". It's "free pectin". Apples have a TON of pectin- you just don't have to pay extra for it.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply simmer off enough liquid until any fruit is thick. For example, I make a blueberry sauce for pancakes and blintzes by just putting some blueberries, sugar, and a pinch of salt in a saucepan, bringing to a boil, and then reducing heat to low until it is as thick as I want. When cooled in the fridge, it will be pretty jammy. (This isn't a canning recipe, it only keeps a few days).

Comment: A friend of mine used the same basic recipe when he brought into work crepes on Bastille Day this year, except he added a little fresh lemon juice to the mix as well.  Got a really nice thick consistency out of it and it was delicious!

Comment: I add juice of one lemon as well, just 10 minutes before cooking is over.

Answer (score 0):

I am rather shocked by the question and the presumption something like gelatine is added to fruit and sugar to make jams and jellies. Jams and jellies are fundamentally made without gelatine or any such product. The fruit contains pectin naturally, and it is this that makes the jam set. Manufactured jam, jellies and marmalades sometimes contain commercially produced pectin, which is labelled as E440.

**Fruits with HIGH in pectin include**: Blackcurrants, Cranberries, Damsons, Plums, Gooseberries, Redcurrants, Cooking Apples and Quince.

**Fruits with MEDIUM pectin content**: Apricots, Greengages, Loganberries, Raspberries and early Blackberries.

**LOW pectin content fruit includes**: Cherries, Elderberries, Medlars, Pears, Rhubarb, Strawberries and late Blackberries.

Fresh fruit contains more pectin than stored fruit. It deteriorates or breaks down as the fruit ages. That is why it is best not to use really ripe fruit for making jams and jellies, but firm slightly unripe or barely ripe is preferable.

I have never made jam using gelatine and would not really care to try either. All my jams are made using one part fruit to one part sugar and jellies are made using a pound of sugar to each pint of juice. If I want to make a jam or jelly with a fruit really low in pectin (so it would not set on its own) for example marrow, I add lemon juice and rind and use jam sugar which contains commercially produced pectin made from citrus peel (which contains a whopping 30% pectin).

Low sugar jams and jellies which do not have a long shelf life are not part of my repertoire. Neither would I care to make jams from fruit which would need commercially produced pectin adding to make them viable.

Comment: I think your first paragraph and last paragraphs are a bit harsh given that you eventually said you use jam sugar (i.e. you add pectin).

Comment: Pectin, not gelatine. There is a huge difference. Harsh? Hummm...

Comment: I think the OP was just asking in general whether some kind of gelling agent was necessary, and lumped gelatin and pectin together. So saying "nothing like gelatin is added" seemed harsh, given that a gelling agent *is* often added (it's just that it's pectin, not gelatin). But the thing that really got me was that you said "Neither would I care to make jams from fruit which would need commercially produced pectin adding to make them viable." the paragraph after saying you use jam sugar containing commercially produced pectin.

Comment: We are talking at cross purposes. I understood the question was: could jam be made without gelatine? An animal product like gelatine has no place in jam. It's shocking someone thinks/presumes it's necessary! I tried to point out I would not want any jam which depended on adding gelatine (e.g. low sugar, diet jam), and would only contemplate using jam sugar as an absolute last resource should it be *very low in pectin*. I would never use bottles of liquid pectin or similar to make jam which would otherwise not work. I think you are being harsh saying I really got you!

Comment: I don't really understand why adding pectin and using regular sugar is bad, but using jam sugar is okay. In any case, for the rest, I merely think that there are more tactful ways to say "jam doesn't use gelatin, it uses pectin".

Comment: Tactful. Right.